# How do I assign elements of an array to a variable in x86 Assembly?

Tags: c++, arrays, x86

I have an array of chars and a temp_char variable, and I want to pass the char at a given index to my temp_char variable, but I really can't figure out how to do it.

I would have thought that something along the lines of

```
mov     temp_char,[index*4+CharsArray]
```

would have worked but it won't compile.

```
movzx   ecx,[index*4+CharsArray]
mov     temp_char,cl
```

will compile but then causes a break in the program.

I can't find anything that really explains how to put things into or get things out of arrays in assembly, if anyone can point me in the right direction, then I'd me most grateful.  So far I've been able to muddle through and get things working, but this has got me completely stumped.

Thanks.

PS

I'm trying to convert a for loop in C++ to __asm for an assignment using a global array

the for loop basically goes:

```
for(int i(0); i<length; ++i)
{
    temp_char = CharArray[i]
    // do other stuff
}
```

so for my __asm I've got

```
void myfunction(int length) {
char temp_char
int index

__asm{
           mov  ebx, len    ;for part       
           mov  index,0             
           jmp  checkend
forloop:   mov  edx,index   ;add one to index           
       add  edx,1
       mov  index,edx

 checkend: cmp  index,ebx    ; check to see if completed
       jge  endfor   

           mov  temp_char,[index*4,CharsArray]   ; program breaks here
           //do other stuff
```

I'm not too bothered if my other assembly is all nonsense, I can sort that out once I can read my characters from my array into my temp variable.

Hope that makes it clearer.

PPS

OK, apparently I have to move from array to register and register to varaible, fair enough, I understand that.  The only problem is how do I do that?  The only way I can get my code to compile is with the aforementioned:

```
movzx    ecx, [index*4+CharsArray]   ;as soon as program gets here it throws exception
mov      temp_char, cl
```

this is all I want to know, if anyone can help, how the above two lines of code should look to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Which compiler, and what is the declaration of index and CharsArray? In these sort of cases, it REALLY helps to have a "complete" piece of code that can be testcompiled, rather than snippets with no context.

Comment: index is an int, CharsArray is a global variable, I'm trying to do it in a C++ harness in visualstudio.

Comment: Right, I thought it might be a MS solution. I can't really help there, since I'm running Linux on my machine. But a "complete" program and some more details of what "causes a break in the program" would certainly help.

Comment: ah well, thanks anyway, who knows maybe it's something glaringly obvious.  I have seen 'add eax,[index*4+arrayName] working, so I don't think that's the problem, but I've got no idea for this.  Give em a high level language any day :)

Comment: you can't move directly memory to memory. at least with old 386. move to register, then to variable.

Comment: Cheers for that, but it won't let me.  I've tried, code snippet in post, if I've done something wrong with that could you elaborate please?

Comment: there is no such instruction. move from the array to a register. then move from the register to the variable.

Comment: it won't let me, it either tells me I've got an operand size conlict, an improper operand type or it compiles and breaks.  I've tried everything I can think of and I can't figure out how to get my character from the array into a register and out again.  any pointers in this regard would be great, this is the only bit that I'm massively stuck on and we've not been shown in any of our notes and I can't find it in the manuals.

Comment: Why index*4? The goal is to get characters so that should be: | mov ebx,index | mov al, CharArray[ebx] | mov temp_char, al | .

Comment: You've got `CharArray` in your C++ but `CharsArray` (with S) in your ASM code.

Comment: rcgldr, thank you so much! You get the brownie points! That was driving me insane, your solution works perfectly.  as for the index*4 I've just looked back and I misread something, apparently that's for integers.  I may be wrong (more than likely).  Anyhow it won't let me give you a star answer for some reason, but you nailed it.

Comment: CharArray, CharsArray - meh!  typeo.

Answer (score 0):

How about just loading cl:

```
mov cl, [index*4+nCharsArray]
mov temp_char, cl
```